# add activity indicator to star and stop when network activity star and stop

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uinavigationbar, uiactivityindicatorview

i'm developing an iOS aplication that uses Parse Backends, and i want to show Acctivity Indicator in my Navigation Bar to star animanting when the network Activity stars in status bar and so stop animating my Activity indicator in navigation bar when network stop the activity in status bar.

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = BLUE_COLOR;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"MyAppname";

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
[self navigationItem].rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
//[activityIndicator startAnimating];



self.photoArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

PFQuery* curQuery = [UserParseHelper query];

[curQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[UserParseHelper currentUser].username];
[curQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    self.mainUser = objects.firstObject;

    if (self.mainUser.geoPoint != nil) {
        [self queryParseMethod];
    } else {
        [self currentLocationIdentifier];
    }
}];

if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    PFQuery *usr = [UserParseHelper query];
    [usr whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[UserParseHelper currentUser].objectId];
    [usr findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        self.userStart = [UserParseHelper alloc];
        self.userStart = objects.firstObject;
        self.userStart.online = @"yes";
        [self.userStart saveEventually];

    }];
}


self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
```

}

Comment: So what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse calls are synchronous, meaning they happen at the same time as other stuff going on in your app, rather than linearly.  When you call `[curQuery findObjectsInBackground...`, your main thread will make a new thread which makes the server call and will eventually run the stuff inside your block.  Then, the main thread immediately goes to the `if ([PFUser currentUser]) {` line, before that block ever gets executed.

You need to do `[activityIndicator startAnimating];` right after your callback blocks, and the first thing you do inside the callback blocks is `[activityIndicator stopAnimating];`

However, you'll probably make your second `startAnimating` call before the first `stopAnimating` call, which is going to have the unintended effect of ending your activityIndicator too early.  You'll have to find a way to keep track of how many things are utilizing that activityIndicator.  i.e., create an int that stores how many things are using the activityIndicator. If it is 0, and you're trying to start the indicator, then increment and start the indicator. If it is > 0, just increment it, as it's already running.  Do the opposite for stopping the activity indicator. If it is > 1, just decrement the int.  If it is == 1, then decrement to 0 and stop the activity indicator.